# iOS Push notification Not working

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I have to implement push notification service to my application, So i had created App ID with push notification enabled in production. there very first time when install the application in my device the push notification allow and don't allow pop-up comes and if it click all . it is not generating the push notification.  next next time when i launched it won't ask for any pop up and i'm not able to generate device token,  Please help me in this.

Thanks,
Nikhil.CH

Comment: Follow this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925

Comment: I followed as a the above tutorial , but still not able to get the device token , but it was asking for the push notification allow confirmation , the very first time,

Comment: -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@",error);
}
Use this code and let me know what is the error

Comment: @baydi  I'm "didFailToRegisterNotificationWithError" also Not triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to be sure that you are getting the token or an error after displaying the "allow" popup. Methods to register notification had a breaking change in iOS8, and if you use old one it will fail silently.

Here a snippet:

```
 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
        // iOS 8
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
}
else{
//.. the old one
}
```

Most of time that something fails can be due to wrong prov profiles and certificates matching, or because you are testing behind a firewall or VPN.
To test them I use [PUSHER](https://github.com/pusher) a wonderful software.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Once you have responded to Push Notifications Permissions Alert details gets saved. To reset that and experience the alert once again follow these steps:

1. Delete your app from the device.
2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

Now, here is step by step process on registering to push notification on iOS app:

**Step 1:** Ask iOS Push Notification settings on device for the app:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil]];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

**Step 2:** Register for notification on the delegate call back from above method call

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)iApplication didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)iNotificationSettings {
    [iApplication registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

**Step 3:** Implement following methods to receive and save the token called from above method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)iApplication didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)iDeviceToken
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)iApplication didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)iError
```

If you are not getting push token then error method `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` must give you some useful information.